# NativeScript flexboxlayout

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to create a flexbox layout with two columns. In the first column, I want to place an image, and in the second column I want to have a listView. I want to have something like that where the green column represents an image.

[image]

Here is what I have try out but it doesn't work as expected, it displays the image at the top and the text below it.

```html
  <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
        <StackLayout  width="1000" height="100%"  class="m-15" >
            <Image src="res://sideimage" horizontalAlignment="left"></Image>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout >
            <ListView  [items]="dataList">
                <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
                        <GridLayout  columns="auto,100" rows="auto,auto" width="2000" >
                            <Label class="confederacy" [nsRouterLink]="['/province', item.confederancy_name]" [text]= "item.confederancy_name" pageTransition="slideLeft" ></Label>
                            <Label class ="arrow-icon" text="&#xf0a9;" class="fas" col="1" row="0" ></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>


    </FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your flexDirection to row like `<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">`. Since you have it as column it'll stack your inner StackLayouts on top of each other, instead of putting them side by side which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use gridlayout instead to sort it.

```html
<GridLayout columns="auto,*" rows="*">
        <StackLayout  col="0" row="0" >
            <Image src="res://sideimage"  stretch="Fill" ></Image>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout  col="1" row="0" >
            <ListView  [items]="dataList">
                <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
                        <GridLayout  columns="auto,100" rows="auto,auto" width="200" >
                            <Label class="confederacy" [nsRouterLink]="['/province', item.conf_name]" [text]= "item.conf_name" pageTransition="slideLeft" ></Label>
                            <Label class ="arrow-icon" text="&#xf0a9;" class="fas" col="1" row="0" ></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
```